# React Native: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to boot up a React Native 0.53.3 app with React 16.2.0 using simulator from Xcode 10.1 on High Sierra.

I previously had some issues that I have since resolved just to get the build to succeed:
[npm-shrinkwrap.json: Could not install from "node_modules/react-navigation/react-native-tab-view@github:react-navigation/react-native-tab-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380006/npm-shrinkwrap-json-could-not-install-from-node-modules-react-navigation-react/56381230#56381230)

[React Native: ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56383771/react-native-cfbundleidentifier-does-not-exist/56395967#56395967)

Now all build succeed even though I continue to get the cfbundleridentifier error:

```
Check dependencies



** BUILD SUCCEEDED **


Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NFIBEngage.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NFIBEngage.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

Even in Metro Bundler it succeeds:

```
Metro Bundler ready.

Loading dependency graph, done.
 BUNDLE  [ios, dev] ./index.ios.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (1667/1667), done.

 BUNDLE  [ios, dev] ./index.ios.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (1/1), done.

 DELTA  [ios, dev] ./index.ios.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (1667/1667), done.

 MAP  [ios, dev] ./index.ios.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (1667/1667), done.
```

So I was wondering why my app when launched in simulator would stay stuck in the splashscreen, that usually only happens when an `index.ios.js` has failed. So I looked at `http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/` and sure enough I saw the following errors:

```
Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

Unhandled JS Exception: Cannot read property 'invocationEventNone' of undefined

Unhandled JS Exception: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

I don't know where its getting `invocationEventNone` from, its not anything written in the codebase, I checked.

```
As far as the `AppRegistry` module, it appears to look fine:

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import KeyboardManager from 'react-native-keyboard-manager';
import NFIBEngage from './App';

KeyboardManager.setToolbarPreviousNextButtonEnable(true);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('NFIBEngage', () => NFIBEngage);
```

Has anyone experienced something like this running versions similar to what I am running? What should I be investigating? How to resolve this?

I followed every solution in here:
[Module AppRegistry is not registered callable module (calling runApplication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43604603/module-appregistry-is-not-registered-callable-module-calling-runapplication)

There was nothing in here that could help:
[React Native Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133086/react-native-module-appregistry-is-not-a-registered-callable-module)

This was not relevant:
[React Native(iOS) Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877706/react-nativeios-module-appregistry-is-not-a-registered-callable-module-callin)

Not relevant:
[React native AppRegistry is not a callable module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630690/react-native-appregistry-is-not-a-callable-module)

I then tried following the solution offered by iDevAmit here:
[React-Native: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969858/react-native-module-appregistry-is-not-a-registered-callable-module)

but it appears my `iOS` which is what I am interested in running right now, is already linked according to this output:

```
rnpm-install info Platform 'ios' module appcenter is already linked
rnpm-install info Linking appcenter android dependency
rnpm-install info Platform 'android' module appcenter has been successfully linked
iOS App Secret is '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' set in ios/NFIBEngage/AppCenter-Config.plist
Added code to initialize iOS AppCenter SDK in ios/NFIBEngage/AppDelegate.m

            Could not install dependencies using CocoaPods.
            Please refer to the documentation to install dependencies manually.

            Error Reason - Could not find "pod" command. Is CocoaPods installed?

Configuring AppCenter Analytics
rnpm-install info Platform 'ios' module appcenter-analytics is already linked
? For the Android app, should user tracking be enabled automatical
ly? (Use arrow keys)
❯ Enable Automatically
  Enable in JavaScript iOS App Secret is '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' set in ios/NFIBEngage/AppCenter-Config.plist
? For the iOS app, should user tracking be enabled automatically?
(Use arrow keys)
❯ Enable Automatically
  Enable in JavaScript
```

I did a Ctrl + C to get out and I do not know if the `CocoaPods` message is related as I have never used it. One time I tried a `pod install` and `zsh` could not find `pod` as a command.

Omar's solution does not work as it gave me `Duplicate declaration "appName"`

None of the other recommendations were applicable and upgrading React Native is not an option for this project.

In my Xcode 10.1 I have the current configuration inside of **Project Settings** -> Advanced button:

[image]

In this post:
[React Native IOS Build CFBundleIdentifier Does not Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298841/react-native-ios-build-cfbundleidentifier-does-not-exist/52814383#52814383)

I already have what SUMIT and priyanga recommended.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41854111/1675954 check this First step is to upgrade react-native

Comment: There are additional recommendations in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52814383/1675954) [which also links to the previous link posted]  Refer to this [closed issue from Sept 2018](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21382#issuecomment-425471215) on github if all else fails

Comment: @RachelGallen, upgrading React Native is not an option for this project. I will clarify that in the post. I also have that configuration for Xcode I will clarify that in the post.

Comment: @RachelGallen, as far as adding `@babel/runtime` I would need to have some idea of how that would fix my problem, I don't just want to start adding packages the project may not need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What resolved this error was by removing the `Instabug` library and code from `App.js` file:

```
export default class appName extends PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._startSentry();
    // if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
    //   const key = base === "prod" ? env.instabug.prod : env.instabug.beta;
    //   Instabug.startWithToken(key, Instabug.invocationEvent.twoFingersSwipe);
    // }
    // Instabug.setIntroMessageEnabled(false);
    // appcenter.trackAppOpened();
  }
```

as I was also getting `invocationEvent` undefined along with that `AppRegistry` error.